# Filter only Value Changes in a postgres table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a very peculiar problem. I have a 44 million record table as below:

```
SKU | Timestamp           | Status
A   | 21-09-2016 12:30:00 | 1  
B   | 21-09-2016 12:30:00 | 1  
C   | 21-09-2016 12:30:00 | 1  
D   | 21-09-2016 12:30:00 | 1  
A   | 21-09-2016 12:39:00 | 0  
B   | 21-09-2016 12:40:00 | 0  
C   | 21-09-2016 12:40:00 | 0  
D   | 21-09-2016 12:45:00 | 0  
A   | 21-09-2016 12:52:00 | 1  
A   | 21-09-2016 12:56:00 | 1  
A   | 21-09-2016 12:58:00 | 1  
B   | 21-09-2016 12:59:00 | 1  
A   | 21-09-2016 21:30:00 | 0
```

Now the requirement is that we should consider only records where the status has changed. For example in the above table, SKU A start with the status as 1 on 21-09-2016 12:30:00. We now look at the future records and see when did the record change so the next change is seen at 21-09-2016 21:30:00 when the status becomes 0. Now we need a table with the following output

```
SKU | Timestamp           | Status
A   | 21-09-2016 12:30:00 | 1  
A   | 21-09-2016 12:39:00 | 0  
A   | 21-09-2016 12:52:00 | 1  
A   | 21-09-2016 21:30:00 | 0  
B   | 21-09-2016 12:30:00 | 1  
B   | 21-09-2016 12:40:00 | 0  
B   | 21-09-2016 12:59:00 | 1  
C   | 21-09-2016 12:30:00 | 1  
C   | 21-09-2016 12:40:00 | 0  
D   | 21-09-2016 12:30:00 | 1  
D   | 21-09-2016 12:45:00 | 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(status) over (partition by sku order by timestamp) as prev_status
      from t
     ) t
where (prev_status is distinct from status) ;
```

Note:  `is distinct from` is a lot like `<>` but it handles `NULL` values more intuitively.

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks for the answer. How much time should we expect this to take in a 44 million record table/

Comment: @SaurabhOmar . . . An index on `(sku, timestamp, status)` should help speed the query.

Answer (score 3):

```
select sku, timestamp, status
from (
    select *, lag(status) over (partition by sku order by timestamp) as prev_status
    from example
    ) s
where prev_status is distinct from status;
```

[Test it here](http://rextester.com/QPGA47848).

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to klin's and Gordon's answers and answering to

> How much time should we expect this to take in a 44 million record table

It is highly depends of the RAM available to the PostgreSQL. Because the results of the subquery should be stored somewhere (and then scanned again).

If RAM amount is enough to store the intermediate result - then all OK, if not - you in the troubles.

For example, on my test on the table with 10,000,000 rows I had cancel the plain query after waiting for more then 15 minutes.

Alternatively, using stored function, it was completed in about 4 minutes which is not much more then the simple ordered select (about 2 minutes).

Here is my test:

```
-- Create data

--drop function if exists foo();
--drop table if exists test;
create table test (i bigserial primary key, sku char(1), ts timestamp, status smallint);

insert into test (sku, ts, status) 
  select
    chr(ascii('A') + (random()*3)::int),
    now()::date + ((random()*100)::int || ' minutes')::interval,
    (random()::int)
  from generate_series(1,10000000);

create index idx on test(sku, ts);

analyse test;

-- And function

create or replace function foo() returns setof test language plpgsql as $$
declare 
  r test;
  p test;
begin
  for r in select * from test order by sku, ts loop
    if p.status is distinct from r.status or p.sku is distinct from r.sku then
      return next r;
    end if;
    p := r;
  end loop;
  return;
end $$;

-- Test queries

explain (analyse, verbose) 
select i, sku, ts, status
from (
    select *, lag(status) over (partition by sku order by ts) as prev_status
    from test
    ) s
where prev_status is distinct from status;
-- Not completed, still working after ~ 15 min

explain analyse select * from test order by sku, ts;
-- Complete in ~2 min

explain (analyse, verbose) select * from foo();
-- Complete in ~3:30 min
```

Comment: Not sure what kind of hardware you have. The select statement with the window function takes only 10 seconds on my desktop computer: https://explain.depesz.com/s/VrVU the "simple" select takes only 5 seconds: https://explain.depesz.com/s/puiO the function takes 16 seconds. https://explain.depesz.com/s/N8B9

Comment: I get your runtimes when generating 50 million rows (instead of the 10 in your example). The window function query takes 2,5minutes: https://explain.depesz.com/s/TGq the plain select about the same: https://explain.depesz.com/s/D4kl and the function call about 3 minutes: https://explain.depesz.com/s/d8Yv

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name So try it on 100 million rows and probably you will get the difference :) However about my HW - it is ~ 6 YO notebook and I think that such difference also because of the low HD speed.